# Integral of measure of super level sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on a compact space $X$ and let $f$ be an integrable function which is bounded by above.

Is there an alternative way of describing the following integral
$$\int _a^\infty \mu(|f|>r) \, dr \,\, ?$$

I'm reading a paper where there is a formula that suggest that the follwing is true

$$\int _a^\infty \mu(|f|>r) \, dr = \int_{\{f>|a|\}} (|f|-a) d\mu$$
 but I'm not sure if this formula is correct and if that's the case, how to prove it.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way to rewrite the first integral is by applying [Tonelli's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions). Indeed,
\begin{align}
\int_a^{\infty}\mu(\{|f| > r\})\,dr = &\ \int_a^{\infty}\int_{\{x:|f(x)| > r\}}\,d\mu(x)\,dr \\
= &\ \int_{\{x:|f(x)| > a\}}\int_a^{|f(x)|}\,dr\,d\mu(x)\\
= &\ \int_{\{|f| > a\}}(|f| - a)\,d\mu \\
= &\ \int_{X}(|f| - a)_+\,d\mu.
\end{align}
I hope this helps!

Comment: Great! It makes sense. Thanks for you answer @Giovanni